# ConnectionError: Error -3 connecting to redis:6379. Try again

Tags: docker, redis, docker-compose

I cannot connect redis client in a docker container with custom redis.conf file. Also even if i remove the code for connect redis with custom redis.conf file docker will still attempt to connect to custom redis file.

Docker.compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
data:
environment:
  - RHOST=redis
command: echo true
networks:
  - redis-net
depends_on:
  - redis
redis:
image: redis:latest
build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: Dockerfile_redis
ports:
  - "6379:6379" 
command: redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf
volumes:
  - ./redis.conf:/etc/redis/redis.conf

networks:
redis-net:

volumes:
redis-data:
```

Dockerfile_redis

```
FROM redis:latest
COPY redis.conf /etc/redis/redis.conf
CMD [ "redis-server", "/etc/redis/redis.conf" ]
```

This is where i connect to redis. I use requirepass in redis.conf file.

```
redis_client = redis.Redis(host='redis',password='password1')
```

Is there a way to find out original redis.conf file that docker uses so then i could just change password to make redis secure ? I just use original redis.conf file which comes after installation of redis to server with "apt install redis" then i change requirepass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this issue finally with help of https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-redis.
There are no need to use dockerfile for redis in this case.

Docker.compose.yml:

```
version: '2'
services:
data:
  command: echo true
  environment:
    - RHOST=Redis
  depends_on:
    - Redis

Redis:
  image: sameersbn/redis:latest
  ports:
    - "6379:6379"
  environment:
    - REDIS_PASSWORD=changeit
  volumes:
    - /srv/docker/redis:/var/lib/redis
  restart: always
```

redis_connect.py

```
redis_client = redis.Redis(host='Redis',port=6379,password='changeit')
```